# Is the list subscription functionality broken?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have ran into an issue with trying to retrieve active subscriptions for a user. Been able to create the subscription and receive updates, but when I try to make a get request to the `/subscriptions` endpoint using the valid `access_token` I have for the user, nothing is returned (empty array).

All of these subscriptions have been made via the beta API, which is what I am pinging to retrieve the active subs.

Been using these docs for reference:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/subscription_list

Comment: Please provide the request body/ response body/ tenant config and so on.

Comment: There is no request body as this is a get. The response body just includes the odata context which is: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions`, and an empty value array. As far as tenant config goes, we have 'openid', 'profile', 'offline_access', 'Calendars.ReadWrite', 'Contacts.ReadWrite', 'Files.ReadWrite.All', 'Notes.ReadWrite.All'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create subscriptions and list them, so the list API is working. Are you sure that the subscriptions you are trying to list are not expired? Please share the request id and date/time and we can look in to it further.

Comment: Thanks, the request id is: `7da08b52-6681-47fa-ab80-56d24a203eff`, and the datetime is: ~October 25th, 10:48 AM PST